# Diab Compiler, Does it automatically optimize array and structure initialization ?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

Hi,

I'm using Diab 5.8.0 as a compiler for my C source code.
I've recognized that if I have a program like this:

```cpp
    typedef struct
    {
        int field_1;
        int field_2;
        int field_3;

    } Struct_Type;

    int main()
    {

    Struct_Type  temp_st = {1,1,1};

    return temp_st.field_1;

    }
```

It seems to be converted to this (the return value is 0 instead of 1)

```cpp
    typedef struct
    {
        int field_1;
        int field_2;
        int field_3;

    } Struct_Type;

    int main()
    {

    Struct_Type  temp_st;

    return temp_st.field_1;

    }
```

There is same problem with array initialization,

This:

```cpp
    int main()
    {   

    int array[3]={1,1,1};  

    return array[0];  

    }
```

is converted to this:

```cpp
    int main()
    {   

    int array[3];  

    return array[0];  

    }
```

I think the issue is from the optimization of Diab Compiler so I do not use any optimize-flag when compile code but the issue is still there.

Could you help me if you know the root cause of this and the solution if I want to init value for struct and array right at the declaration?

Comment: How do you test the return value from `main()`? In both of your example conversions, uninitialised values are returned.

Comment: - How do I test a return value ? 
-->I use RTRT testing tool of IBM.

- I obviously init value for local struct (example 1) and local array (example 2), so the return values should be 1. I've checked it by using Visual Studio, and the return values are 1.

Comment: My point was that without initialisation, my program does not return `0` but the arbitrary value `4205729`.

Comment: Yes, I got your point.